# Using retrofit and gson empty body using a specific URL

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, gson

I'm trying to consume a JSON URL using retrofit and gson, the implemented solution is very similar to what's described in the tutorial below:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-retrofit-2--cms-27792

But, when I want to consume the following url:
https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/leagues-classic-standings/624264

Even if the url is returning JSON data (we can verify this by pasting the URL in the browser for example), I'm getting an empty response and I have the following exception:

> retrofit gson java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1
>   path $

I don't understand why and why I'm missing in the code. Could you help, please?

The code is on github: 
https://github.com/anaselhajjaji/android-samples/tree/master/JsonSample

POJO Classes: https://github.com/anaselhajjaji/android-samples/tree/master/JsonSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/anas/jsonsample/model

Thank you

Comment: can you please add some codes. Especially your pojo

Comment: As explained in the tutoria, just paste the JSON content in: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ but this happens before parsing the json, the GET request returns empty body

Comment: I know how to create pojo but I dont know how you applied it

Comment: OK I will paste in the question the pojo classes.

Comment: POJO Classes: https://github.com/anaselhajjaji/android-samples/tree/master/JsonSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/anas/jsonsample/model

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution, I changed the User-Agent value in the header, apparently the server doesn't accept the value sent by retrofit-okhttp, the value was something like okhttp3... I changed it to another value.

Comment: still i'm facing same issue can you share sample code

Comment: You saved my day.

Answer (score -1):

Ok some serializers doesnt accept null values. In your case can you try to add below in your builder

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(new NullOnEmptyConverterFactory())
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

And also add your delegation factory

```
class NullOnEmptyConverterFactory implements Converter.Factory {
  @Override public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBody(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
    final Converter<ResponseBody, ?> delegate = retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(this, type, annotations);
    return new Converter<>() {
      @Override public void convert(ResponseBody body) {
        if (body.contentLength() == 0) return null;
        return delegate.convert(body);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: refer to [link](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1554#issuecomment-178633697)

Comment: this is not the solution, this is to handle empty response. My problem is the response is not empty and you can see JSON content if you open the url in browser but passing by retrofit2 the response is empty.

Comment: Check this [issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1691) and check the informations you gave after downvote !

Comment: This is not the solution to my problem, I finally found the solution, I changed the User-Agent value in the header, apparently the server doesn't accept the value sent by retrofit-okhttp, the value was something like okhttp3... I changed it to another value.